# How to build an Intel binary on an M1 Mac from the command line with the standard Apple version of clang?

Tags: macos, command-line, clang, cross-compiling, intel

I'm playing with some C code on my M1 MacBook Air and looking at the assembly produced with various optimization levels.

I'm building a single C file from the commandline with the most basic command:

> `cc foo.c -o foo`

What switch do I use to build an Intel binary instead of ARM? Are there different flavours of Intel? 32 vs 64 bit? Maybe even older CPU instruction sets? This is surprisingly hard to Google for, but I'm new to the Apple ecosystem.

What about fat binaries? How would I build a single binary that contained both Intel and ARM code from the commandline?

(For the purposes of this question I'm only interested in what I can do on the commandline. If I need to set up XCode projects or environment variables, then I'll accept an answer that just says "You can't do it with just the commandline".)

Comment: I'm thinking I might need some SDK or object files for the linking stage too that weren't installed by default?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Intel 32 bit is not executable on macOS since Catalina. Every Mac since 2006, except the original Intel Mac mini with Core Solo processor, is 64 bit capable.

Intel:
`clang -o myTool-x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -arch x86_64 main.c`

ARM64:
`clang -o myTool-arm64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -arch arm64 main.c`

FAT binary:
`lipo myTool-x86_64 myTool-arm64 -create -output myTool`

Comment: I knew 32 bit isn't supported any more but you never know when things are still in the tools. Then again I still have an old Mac with Mountain Lion so I can probably build my code on that. It wasn't crucial anyway, just curiosity of what the asm might look like. Thanks for the working answer!

Comment: I use the second command on my intel mac to generate arm64 assembly, but it gives: 
main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'unistd.h' file not found
#include <unistd.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.